# apply regex only when a character is not at start and end

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to find and replace PHP variables in PHP files from vb.net. I successfully do this within a loop:

```
"\B\$foo\b"
"\B\$boo\b"
.....
```

now I want to exclude replacement when reading Smarty style files.

Smarty variables are like PHP variables but within { and } characters.

for example would like to find and replace $foo in this text, but do not touch {$boo}:

> this is just an example of $foo and not {$boo}!

need to know correct regular expression that works in vb.net

Comment: Just to clarify, you also would still want to replace `$bar` and `$baz` in `some example of {$bar and $baz}`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex that has lookaround:

```
(?<!\{)\B\$foo\b(?!\})
```

Lookaround tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

EDIT: I'm tempted to use balancing groups, but I won't for simplicity, so here is my solution as per your comment:

```
(?<=(?:^|\})[^{]*)\B\$foo\b(?=[^}]*(?:$|\{))
```

Comment: ok it works great for {$foo} but after some testing I find that this not work for something like: {sometext $foo wewerwer} I mean it select $foo in this example, but should not select it

Comment: Let me know if the new regex fixes it.

Comment: I forgot to change the `?!` to `?=`. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

A small change to your Regex to ensure that { and } do NOT match via negative lookbehind and lookahead:

```
(?<!\{)\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*(?!\})
```

The **(?!\})** means don't match } ahead of this.

The **(?<!\{)** means don't match { behind this.